# android dagger2 inject error cannot cast

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Getting this error when onItemSelected() method is called what this error mean?and maybe you have any ideas how can it be fixed?

Method which is called in MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onAdviceBodyItemSelected(Advice advice) {
    SideEffectReportActivity.start(this, advice);
}
```

Interface

```
public interface MainRouter extends BodyRouter {

void onAdviceBodyItemSelected(Advice advice);

   }
```

,
Fragment

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        getPresenter().setRouter(activity);
        mAdvicePresenter.getList(mBody);
        activity.resolveToolbar(this);
    }
```

,
Presenter class

```
public class AdviceListPresenter extends BasePresenter<AdviceListView,` 

    MainRouter> {

    private static final String TAG = "advicelistpresenter";
    private



final GetSideEffectListByCategoryInteractor mGetSideEffectListInteractor;

@Inject
AdviceListPresenter(GetSideEffectListByCategoryInteractor getSideEffectListInteractor) {
    mGetSideEffectListInteractor = getSideEffectListInteractor;
}

@Override public void onStart() {

}

@Override public void onStop() {
    mGetSideEffectListInteractor.unsubscribe();
}


void getList(Body body) {
    getView().onStartLoading();
    mGetSideEffectListInteractor.execute(body.name(), new Subscriber<List<Advice>>() {
        @Override public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
            getView().onLoaded();
        }

        @Override public void onNext(List<Advice> groups) {
            getView().onLoaded();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq--------------------------------: ");
            getView().updateAList(groups);
        }
    });
}


void onItemSelected(Advice advice) {
  // getRouter().openSideEffect(advice);
    //getRouter().onAdviceItemSelected(advice);
   // Log.e(TAG," ADVICE :" + advice.bodypartProblemsGroup);

    Log.e(TAG,"router :" + getRouter());
    getRouter().onAdviceBodyItemSelected(advice);
}
void onGItemSelected(AdviceGroup adviceGroup) {
    // getRouter().openSideEffect(advice);
    //getRouter().onAdviceItemSelected(advice);
   // Log.e(TAG," ADVICE :" + advice.bodypartProblemsGroup);
}
}
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.ct.rrapp, PID: 15838
>                                                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ct.rrapp.presentation.side_Effect.SideEffectReportActivity cannot be cast to nl.creativeict.radiotherapp.presentation.main.MainRouter
>                                                                                    at com.ct.rrapp.presentation.side_Effect.advice_list.AdviceListPresenter.onItemSelected(AdviceListPresenter.java:80)
>                                                                                    at com.ct.rrapp.presentation.side_Effect.advice_list.AdviceListFragment$1.onItemSelected(AdviceListFragment.java:93)
>                                                                                    at com.ct.rrapp.presentation.side_Effect.advice_list.common.AdviceListAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$1(AdviceListAdapter.java:55)
>                                                                                    at com.ct.rrapp.presentation.side_Effect.advice_list.common.AdviceListAdapter$$Lambda$4.onClick(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: why you tag this dagger? there's no sign of dagger in your code.

Comment: @Inject isn't it dagger annotation?

Comment: oh, sorry, missed that alone `@Inject`

Comment: and I think this error have something to do with injections

Comment: it explodes after click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by this line:

```
@Override
public void onAdviceBodyItemSelected(Advice advice) {
    SideEffectReportActivity.start(this, advice);
}
```

And this exception message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:SideEffectReportActivity cannot be cast to MainRouter

One may conclude, that static method `SideEffectReportActivity#start(*, Advice)` expects `MainRouter` as first argument, whereas the class, that `this` object is instance of, does not implement `MainRouter` interface.

If `this` object is an instance of `MainActivity`, that means, that your activity doesn't implement `MainRouter`.